# In/on/with placing an order. What's the difference?

Tags: grammar, word-usage, prepositions, sentence-construction, american-english

**For example:**

*We are in charge of helping the customer **in/on/with** placing there orders online.*

Which preposition should I use? Also what's the difference? Thank you in advance.

PS. Please excuse my grammar, I'm still learning.

Comment: "there orders" should be "their orders".

Comment: As you may know, you don't _need_ **in**, **on** or **with**: "We are in charge of helping customers place their orders online."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think I would use 'in'.

> We are in charge of helping the customer **on** placing their orders online.

I would say that if I help the customer from the moment they have placed an order. Another usage example would be at a hotel: "On checking in the concierge will take your bags to the room."

> We are in charge of helping the customer **with** placing their orders online.

I would say that if I help them choose their items, or fill out the order, or advise generally on the products. Another usage example would be at a hotel: "Will the concierge help me with the bags?"